# Matlab to Python Conversion CO2 Concentration

Tags: python, matlab, converters

I'm new to Python and am trying to get my head around it. I have some code from Matlab that I want to convert to Python and I'm struggling with it. I tried using OMPC converter but so far am finding it hard to use without the built in functions compared with Matlab. Some of my code is as follows:

```
start_year=1;                % Model Start Date
end_year=100000;              % End date
dt=1;                        % Incremented time
time=start_year:dt:end_year; % Time variable
N=length(time);              % Number of incrementes 

E=1;

tauC=50;
tauC_fat=[30 300 10000];

C=zeros(1,N);            % CO2 Concentration
C_fat=zeros(1,N);
C0=0;
C(1)=C0;
C_fat(1)=C0;
```

Also I'm using the Spyder version of Python 3.6 which I downloaded from Anaconda, is this a good place to start my python learning?

Comment: What exactly are you struggling with? Other than `time=start_year:dt:end_year;` it looks like everything is a straightforward conversion of code (half of the lines just require removal of `;` but they would still work).

Comment: You can use `numpy` for the arrays e.g. [`numpy.zeros()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html). Also note that python uses zero-based indexing. Comments require `#` not `%`.

Comment: Note, there is no "Spyder version" of python. Spyder is an IDE that is meant to emulate RStudio

Comment: how would I code the     time=start_year:dt:end_year; bit?

Answer (score 0):

The code you displayed is not really python.

Matlab and python are totally different animals. Numpy and Matplotlib, which are python extensions used frequently in the scientific realm, share a lot of concepts with matlab, but the underlying syntax is distintly pythonic.

I would start with https://learnpythonthehardway.org/python3/index.html for a quick and dirty introduction to Python (Its free as of the time of my writing: you can ignore the solicitations for a purchase, although if you did buy, i believe its money well spent). In addition, these official documentation pages should always be handy when coding in python

Python Language Reference:

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/index.html#reference-index

Python Standard Library:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/index.html#library-index

Comment: This might be a handy link to include in your answer too: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html